# Making graph too large for sfdp

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot, graph-visualization

I was trying to visualize a large graph with sfdp.
The graph has 5134 edges and 1735 nodes.
When I try to generate the .png:

```
sfdp -x -Goverlap=scale -Tpng data.dot > data.png
```

I get this:

```
sfdp: graph is too large for cairo-renderer bitmaps. Scaling by 0.687429 to fit
sfdp: failure to create cairo surface: out of memory
Segmentation fault.
```

Probably the problem is that my nodes are not dots, because when I generate de .png without "-Goverlap=scale" there is no problem but the graph is unreadable.

There is something I can do?
There is another tool that can do this?

Answer (score 5):

The following GraphViz interest group conversation implies that changing the "overlap" value to "prism" may solve your problem.  Yifan Hu, one of the authors of `dot`, implies that prism is more memory efficient than scale.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.video.graphviz/6925

so:

```
sfdp -x -Goverlap=prism -Tpng data.dot > data.png
```

If you aren't using the latest version of GraphViz, it may be worth updating it. More recent versions may be more memory efficient.

Comment: I highly recommend using latest version, switching from 2.36 to 2.39 made everything simply work for a relatively big graph.

Answer (score 2):

```
dot -Tsvg 99winsert.gv -v > out.svg
```

try transform to svg and then transform svg to png